# Ironpython Array[byte] to byte string

Tags: arrays, string, ironpython

Within IronPython 2.7, I am running a few calls to a .Net dll :

```
from System.Guid import NewGuid, ToByteArray
from System import Array, Byte
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFile( ThePathToDLLFile )
from MyDLL import *
...
g = NewGuid()
buffer = ToByteArray(g)
ret = myDllMethodToFillBuffer( buffer )
```

Some methods like 'myDllMethod' return a buffer of type Array[byte]:

```
>>> type(buffer)
<type 'Array[Byte]'>
```

I am strugling to find the right way to convert the Array[byte] to Python 'string byte', IE '\x01\x02\x03 ...'

After a bit of googling I found the way to do the opposite conversion (string byte to byte[array])

```
byteArray = Array[Byte](ord(c) for c in byteList)
```

How should I convert a variable length byte[array] to string byte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `bytes` function:

```
>>> bytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray())
b'\x14\x15\xd4\x05\xe4\xc2\xa8N\x9a\x99\t\x82\xe41r\xb3'
```